# How can I get a list of Linux system calls and number of args they take automatically?

Tags: c, system-calls

I writing a Linux system call map for the radare2 debugger. This means providing a huge static array mapping system call number to a syscall name name and the number of arguments it takes. This was easy for OpenBSD as the syscall numbers are defined in sys/syscall.h and in a comment above each is the number of args. It was just a matter of writing a script to parse this and throw out the C code for the array.

On linux however, we do not have this luxury. It is easy to get the syscall number from the kernel headers, but how should I get the number of args? The only ideas I have are:

1) Type them in manually. For each and every arch (they vary between arches in linux). All 300+ of the damned things. No way!

2) Parse manual pages.

3) Write a script which tries to call each syscall with 0, 1, 2... args until the program builds. Won't work for varargs, but do syscalls support that?

There has to be a better way. Please help!

Comment: For an example of varargs, see `open()`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth what do you mean by this? `sys_open()` has exactly 3 arguments.

Comment: There's a [great table in the Chromium OS docs](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/master/constants/syscalls.md#x86_64-64_bit). I suggest finding out how they did it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`strace` ([home page](https://strace.io/)) has tables with all this stuff in (see `linux/<platform>/syscallent.h`). Source code available in [GitHub/strace](https://github.com/strace/strace.git) and [GitLab/strace](https://gitlab.com/strace/strace.git). For example, list of syscalls in x86_64 architecture are in [this link](https://gitlab.com/strace/strace/-/blob/master/src/linux/x86_64/syscallent.h).

Answer (score 6):

The only list I know is the kernel source, in [include/linux/syscalls.h](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=include/linux/syscalls.h;hb=HEAD).  But that is only by name, not number; I think you need to use the syscall.h header for your particular platform to get the numbers.  And there are a few #ifdefs in that file...

Comment: it is the number of arguments for each system call i need

Comment: @vext01:  I assume you also need the types?  Because some arguments can be 32-bit and others 64-bit, I believe.  Anyway, if you click the link to the header source I provided, you will see that the complete signature of each system call is there.

Comment: I do not need types for now, so I can parse the systrace implementation.

Answer (score 4):

[This](https://filippo.io/linux-syscall-table/) post is worth reading.
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

Documentation parsing:

http://asm.sourceforge.net/syscall.html Parse the HTML inside the `<pre>` tags.

or

http://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/ Convert JSON http://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/syscalls-2.6.35.4.js

Answer (score 2):

There are system calls with variable numbers of arguments - witness the `open()` call at the C level, where the third parameter is optional (might not be optional at the assembler level).

Your best bet might be to find the system calls identified by name in `syscalls.h` in the (preprocessed) source of the other system headers.  From those, you can count the number of arguments.  Just getting the right headers in place might be tricky, and there might conceivably be system calls that are never exposed as C functions directly (I haven't looked to see; it is fairly unlikely, though).

You might look at how another debugger, such as GDB, does the same job.

Comment: @vext01: maybe - but not on platforms w/o DWARF, so there may be ideas in there that can be used.   And the DWARF info has to come from somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

(Sorry) no idea on *number of args* other then man-pages, but for *syscall number*:

See [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/421907/246562) on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange

[This](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/sh/include/uapi/asm/unistd_64.h) is probably the piece of code in the kernel repo, not sure.

What I am sure is the following on my machine :)

**/usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h**

```
#ifndef _ASM_X86_UNISTD_64_H
#define _ASM_X86_UNISTD_64_H 1

#define __NR_read 0
#define __NR_write 1
#define __NR_open 2
#define __NR_close 3
#define __NR_stat 4
#define __NR_fstat 5
#define __NR_lstat 6
#define __NR_poll 7
#define __NR_lseek 8
#define __NR_mmap 9
#define __NR_mprotect 10
#define __NR_munmap 11
#define __NR_brk 12
#define __NR_rt_sigaction 13
#define __NR_rt_sigprocmask 14
#define __NR_rt_sigreturn 15
#define __NR_ioctl 16
#define __NR_pread64 17
#define __NR_pwrite64 18
#define __NR_readv 19
#define __NR_writev 20
#define __NR_access 21
#define __NR_pipe 22
#define __NR_select 23
#define __NR_sched_yield 24
#define __NR_mremap 25
#define __NR_msync 26
#define __NR_mincore 27
#define __NR_madvise 28
#define __NR_shmget 29
#define __NR_shmat 30
#define __NR_shmctl 31
#define __NR_dup 32
#define __NR_dup2 33
#define __NR_pause 34
#define __NR_nanosleep 35
#define __NR_getitimer 36
#define __NR_alarm 37
#define __NR_setitimer 38
#define __NR_getpid 39
#define __NR_sendfile 40
#define __NR_socket 41
#define __NR_connect 42
#define __NR_accept 43
#define __NR_sendto 44
#define __NR_recvfrom 45
#define __NR_sendmsg 46
#define __NR_recvmsg 47
#define __NR_shutdown 48
#define __NR_bind 49
#define __NR_listen 50
#define __NR_getsockname 51
#define __NR_getpeername 52
#define __NR_socketpair 53
#define __NR_setsockopt 54
#define __NR_getsockopt 55
#define __NR_clone 56
#define __NR_fork 57
#define __NR_vfork 58
#define __NR_execve 59
#define __NR_exit 60
#define __NR_wait4 61
#define __NR_kill 62
#define __NR_uname 63
#define __NR_semget 64
#define __NR_semop 65
#define __NR_semctl 66
#define __NR_shmdt 67
#define __NR_msgget 68
#define __NR_msgsnd 69
#define __NR_msgrcv 70
#define __NR_msgctl 71
#define __NR_fcntl 72
#define __NR_flock 73
#define __NR_fsync 74
#define __NR_fdatasync 75
#define __NR_truncate 76
#define __NR_ftruncate 77
#define __NR_getdents 78
#define __NR_getcwd 79
#define __NR_chdir 80
#define __NR_fchdir 81
#define __NR_rename 82
#define __NR_mkdir 83
#define __NR_rmdir 84
#define __NR_creat 85
#define __NR_link 86
#define __NR_unlink 87
#define __NR_symlink 88
#define __NR_readlink 89
#define __NR_chmod 90
#define __NR_fchmod 91
#define __NR_chown 92
#define __NR_fchown 93
#define __NR_lchown 94
#define __NR_umask 95
#define __NR_gettimeofday 96
#define __NR_getrlimit 97
#define __NR_getrusage 98
#define __NR_sysinfo 99
#define __NR_times 100
#define __NR_ptrace 101
#define __NR_getuid 102
#define __NR_syslog 103
#define __NR_getgid 104
#define __NR_setuid 105
#define __NR_setgid 106
#define __NR_geteuid 107
#define __NR_getegid 108
#define __NR_setpgid 109
#define __NR_getppid 110
#define __NR_getpgrp 111
#define __NR_setsid 112
#define __NR_setreuid 113
#define __NR_setregid 114
#define __NR_getgroups 115
#define __NR_setgroups 116
#define __NR_setresuid 117
#define __NR_getresuid 118
#define __NR_setresgid 119
#define __NR_getresgid 120
#define __NR_getpgid 121
#define __NR_setfsuid 122
#define __NR_setfsgid 123
#define __NR_getsid 124
#define __NR_capget 125
#define __NR_capset 126
#define __NR_rt_sigpending 127
#define __NR_rt_sigtimedwait 128
#define __NR_rt_sigqueueinfo 129
#define __NR_rt_sigsuspend 130
#define __NR_sigaltstack 131
#define __NR_utime 132
#define __NR_mknod 133
#define __NR_uselib 134
#define __NR_personality 135
#define __NR_ustat 136
#define __NR_statfs 137
#define __NR_fstatfs 138
#define __NR_sysfs 139
#define __NR_getpriority 140
#define __NR_setpriority 141
#define __NR_sched_setparam 142
#define __NR_sched_getparam 143
#define __NR_sched_setscheduler 144
#define __NR_sched_getscheduler 145
#define __NR_sched_get_priority_max 146
#define __NR_sched_get_priority_min 147
#define __NR_sched_rr_get_interval 148
#define __NR_mlock 149
#define __NR_munlock 150
#define __NR_mlockall 151
#define __NR_munlockall 152
#define __NR_vhangup 153
#define __NR_modify_ldt 154
#define __NR_pivot_root 155
#define __NR__sysctl 156
#define __NR_prctl 157
#define __NR_arch_prctl 158
#define __NR_adjtimex 159
#define __NR_setrlimit 160
#define __NR_chroot 161
#define __NR_sync 162
#define __NR_acct 163
#define __NR_settimeofday 164
#define __NR_mount 165
#define __NR_umount2 166
#define __NR_swapon 167
#define __NR_swapoff 168
#define __NR_reboot 169
#define __NR_sethostname 170
#define __NR_setdomainname 171
#define __NR_iopl 172
#define __NR_ioperm 173
#define __NR_create_module 174
#define __NR_init_module 175
#define __NR_delete_module 176
#define __NR_get_kernel_syms 177
#define __NR_query_module 178
#define __NR_quotactl 179
#define __NR_nfsservctl 180
#define __NR_getpmsg 181
#define __NR_putpmsg 182
#define __NR_afs_syscall 183
#define __NR_tuxcall 184
#define __NR_security 185
#define __NR_gettid 186
#define __NR_readahead 187
#define __NR_setxattr 188
#define __NR_lsetxattr 189
#define __NR_fsetxattr 190
#define __NR_getxattr 191
#define __NR_lgetxattr 192
#define __NR_fgetxattr 193
#define __NR_listxattr 194
#define __NR_llistxattr 195
#define __NR_flistxattr 196
#define __NR_removexattr 197
#define __NR_lremovexattr 198
#define __NR_fremovexattr 199
#define __NR_tkill 200
#define __NR_time 201
#define __NR_futex 202
#define __NR_sched_setaffinity 203
#define __NR_sched_getaffinity 204
#define __NR_set_thread_area 205
#define __NR_io_setup 206
#define __NR_io_destroy 207
#define __NR_io_getevents 208
#define __NR_io_submit 209
#define __NR_io_cancel 210
#define __NR_get_thread_area 211
#define __NR_lookup_dcookie 212
#define __NR_epoll_create 213
#define __NR_epoll_ctl_old 214
#define __NR_epoll_wait_old 215
#define __NR_remap_file_pages 216
#define __NR_getdents64 217
#define __NR_set_tid_address 218
#define __NR_restart_syscall 219
#define __NR_semtimedop 220
#define __NR_fadvise64 221
#define __NR_timer_create 222
#define __NR_timer_settime 223
#define __NR_timer_gettime 224
#define __NR_timer_getoverrun 225
#define __NR_timer_delete 226
#define __NR_clock_settime 227
#define __NR_clock_gettime 228
#define __NR_clock_getres 229
#define __NR_clock_nanosleep 230
#define __NR_exit_group 231
#define __NR_epoll_wait 232
#define __NR_epoll_ctl 233
#define __NR_tgkill 234
#define __NR_utimes 235
#define __NR_vserver 236
#define __NR_mbind 237
#define __NR_set_mempolicy 238
#define __NR_get_mempolicy 239
#define __NR_mq_open 240
#define __NR_mq_unlink 241
#define __NR_mq_timedsend 242
#define __NR_mq_timedreceive 243
#define __NR_mq_notify 244
#define __NR_mq_getsetattr 245
#define __NR_kexec_load 246
#define __NR_waitid 247
#define __NR_add_key 248
#define __NR_request_key 249
#define __NR_keyctl 250
#define __NR_ioprio_set 251
#define __NR_ioprio_get 252
#define __NR_inotify_init 253
#define __NR_inotify_add_watch 254
#define __NR_inotify_rm_watch 255
#define __NR_migrate_pages 256
#define __NR_openat 257
#define __NR_mkdirat 258
#define __NR_mknodat 259
#define __NR_fchownat 260
#define __NR_futimesat 261
#define __NR_newfstatat 262
#define __NR_unlinkat 263
#define __NR_renameat 264
#define __NR_linkat 265
#define __NR_symlinkat 266
#define __NR_readlinkat 267
#define __NR_fchmodat 268
#define __NR_faccessat 269
#define __NR_pselect6 270
#define __NR_ppoll 271
#define __NR_unshare 272
#define __NR_set_robust_list 273
#define __NR_get_robust_list 274
#define __NR_splice 275
#define __NR_tee 276
#define __NR_sync_file_range 277
#define __NR_vmsplice 278
#define __NR_move_pages 279
#define __NR_utimensat 280
#define __NR_epoll_pwait 281
#define __NR_signalfd 282
#define __NR_timerfd_create 283
#define __NR_eventfd 284
#define __NR_fallocate 285
#define __NR_timerfd_settime 286
#define __NR_timerfd_gettime 287
#define __NR_accept4 288
#define __NR_signalfd4 289
#define __NR_eventfd2 290
#define __NR_epoll_create1 291
#define __NR_dup3 292
#define __NR_pipe2 293
#define __NR_inotify_init1 294
#define __NR_preadv 295
#define __NR_pwritev 296
#define __NR_rt_tgsigqueueinfo 297
#define __NR_perf_event_open 298
#define __NR_recvmmsg 299
#define __NR_fanotify_init 300
#define __NR_fanotify_mark 301
#define __NR_prlimit64 302
#define __NR_name_to_handle_at 303
#define __NR_open_by_handle_at 304
#define __NR_clock_adjtime 305
#define __NR_syncfs 306
#define __NR_sendmmsg 307
#define __NR_setns 308
#define __NR_getcpu 309
#define __NR_process_vm_readv 310
#define __NR_process_vm_writev 311
#define __NR_kcmp 312
#define __NR_finit_module 313
#define __NR_sched_setattr 314
#define __NR_sched_getattr 315
#define __NR_renameat2 316
#define __NR_seccomp 317
#define __NR_getrandom 318
#define __NR_memfd_create 319
#define __NR_kexec_file_load 320
#define __NR_bpf 321
#define __NR_execveat 322
#define __NR_userfaultfd 323
#define __NR_membarrier 324
#define __NR_mlock2 325
#define __NR_copy_file_range 326
#define __NR_preadv2 327
#define __NR_pwritev2 328
#define __NR_pkey_mprotect 329
#define __NR_pkey_alloc 330
#define __NR_pkey_free 331
#define __NR_statx 332
#define __NR_io_pgetevents 333
#define __NR_rseq 334
#define __NR_pidfd_send_signal 424
#define __NR_io_uring_setup 425
#define __NR_io_uring_enter 426
#define __NR_io_uring_register 427
#define __NR_open_tree 428
#define __NR_move_mount 429
#define __NR_fsopen 430
#define __NR_fsconfig 431
#define __NR_fsmount 432
#define __NR_fspick 433
#define __NR_pidfd_open 434
#define __NR_clone3 435

#endif /* _ASM_X86_UNISTD_64_H */
```