# How to get the parameter list and their type of a system call?

Tags: c++, c, linux, system

I want to know if there is a way to get all the parameters and their types of a linux system call... as a list or any data structure. using C or C++ definitely.
There are some way which gives the memory addresses of the parameters but I need the real values.

Or if anybody could tell me how to get real values from those memory addresses? because those addresses holds different types of values in different time.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: `man <name ot the syscall>`

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: in this link [link](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6100?page=0,1) you will find an example which demonstrates reading SYS_write system call registers. I want this with other system calls and want to read real values instead of memory addresses.
For example in that program output is like: 
Write called with 1, 1075154944, 30
.Here 2nd value is an address.

Comment: "man" is not appropriate because i need it in runtime.

Comment: ***[Here is a list of i386 linux system calls](http://asm.sourceforge.net/syscall.html#p3)***.  via Google search phrase ***"List of linux system calls"***  (includes parameter information for each)

Comment: guys... i need it in run-time... dynamically.
is there any way? I think its not a good idea to write 330 switch cases for each and every system calls.

Comment: Are you looking for `strace`? It already has all the 150719 `case`s written for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking here, looks like it should get you where you're going:

[How can I get a list of Linux system calls and number of args they take automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604007/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-linux-system-calls-and-number-of-args-they-take-automati)

Comment: this only gives the number of parameters... i need the parameter types also. :(

Comment: If you have permission, you can view the header file where these are defined, which should have the signature of each call, allowing you to get the types. `root/include/linux/syscalls.h`. You should be able to parse that at runtime and get what you need. See [syscalls.h](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/syscalls.h?id=HEAD)

Comment: yes. but i'm confused... should i read it as text and parse the required information... or is there any other smart way to do that? may be meta programming or any way to determine function parameter types at runtime.

Comment: I'd say if any of the other proposed solutions, such as strace, don't do what you need, then you parse it and get the info you need in that manner.